# Установка модуля в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, есть ли способ задать установку модуля/библиотеки для Python через код. К примеру, если код запускается на машине, где модуль ещё не установлен, то он сначала устанавливается автоматически при запуске кода.

Comment: Если вы про виртуальную машину, то можно установить, как обычно.

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду, допустим на другом компьютере запускаем и чтобы библиотека сама устанавливалась, если её нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал Вам воспользоваться pyinstaller’ом. Это действительно хорошая вещь, которая компилирует ваш код вместе с дополнительными библиотеками в (.exe). Фишка в том, что для открытия такой программы на другом компьютере не требуется установленный python. Кажется, это именно то, что вам нужно.

А теперь ближе к теме:

```
import os
os.system('pip install *библиотека*')
```

Но все же советую первый способ!